# What does _AVrfpGetProcessName do?

Tags: windows, winapi, application-verifier

What does the function "_AVrfpGetProcessName" does ? Is there any link where I can find the detailed description of this function ?

Comment: What is the practical programming problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)'s checked version of the normal GetProcessName WIN32 API function.

Comment: Yeah even i think so but isnt' there any proper link that can give the insight on this function? Or should I just add the functionality of App Verifier and GetProcessName?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. AppVerifier is a development utility that you install and enable for certain apps that you want monitored for 'sanity'. It's not something you would normally deploy in the field or should explicitly account for in the code.